# Why is undefined being returned for Meteor.call() in client?

Tags: javascript, twitter, meteor

So I'm attempting to access the twitter REST API and retrieve the screen name of a tweet. I feel like my code will be better explanation:

I'm calling the method 'screenName' from the isClient() :

```
  'click button': function () {
    Meteor.call('screenName',
      function(error,result) {
        if (error) {
          console.log(error);
        }
        else {
          window.alert(result);
        }
      }
    )
  }
```

And for some reason the method returns undefined when its actually logging in the screen name of the twitter account on the console.

```
Meteor.methods({
  'screenName': function() {
      T.get('search/tweets',
      {
        q:'#UCLA',
        count:1
      },
      function(err,data,response) {
        console.log(data.statuses[0].user.screen_name);
        return data.statuses[0].user.screen_name;
      }
    )
  }
```

If someone could please help me with this. Thank you so much!

Comment: Classic scope issue. You `return` in the callback of your `T.get`, not in the Meteor method. You should search for `wrapAsync`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server method needs to be synchronous. The callback in the method is returning **after** the method has already returned `undefined`. I'd like to be more specific but I'm not sure what library you are using.

You can get a feel for this by looking at the examples from the [HTTP.call](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/http_call) documentation. Your code could look something like this:

```
Tget = Meteor.wrapAsync(T.get);

Meteor.methods({
  'screenName': function() {
    try {
      var result = Tget('search/tweets', {q:'#UCLA', count:1});
      return result.statuses[0].user.screen_name;
    } catch (e) {
      return false;
    }
  }
});
```

See [the docs](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_wrapasync) for more information on `wrapAsync`.

Comment: @halapgos1 I updated the answer with `wrapAsync` - hopefully that just works.

Comment: Fixed. Thanks @kyll. :)

Comment: You're welcome =D. Let's close one question as a duplicate now, this is confusing me (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31685359/make-meteor-method-synchronous).

Comment: I tried this and it keeps returning false. Not sure why though. Oh I see what it is. Basically, the Node module that I'm using for twitter requires a callback so I'm assuming the library is not able to read the request because its not even in the proper syntax, hence, its confused. I feel like that reasoning makes sense

Answer (score 0):

You are only returning `data.statuses[0].user.screen_name` from your inner function. You need to return it from your `screenName` method to have it available in `Meteor.call()`.

Comment: Hey! Yeah, I attempted that before as well, and it didn't work due to scope issues. The variable data is then shown as undefined, which makes sense.