# Attempting to use MeteorJS w/twit Node Module, Error: [TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'request']

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter, meteor

So I'm using MeteorJS w/the twit Node module to access the screen name of a tweet. Still just testing the code to see if I can retrieve the JSON from twitter.

Here is my code:

```
  var Tget = Meteor.wrapAsync(T.get);

  Meteor.methods({
    'screenName' : function() {
      try {
        var result = Tget('search/tweets', {q:'#UCLA',count:1});
        JSON.stringify(result);
        console.log(result);
      }
      catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
        return false; 
    }
  }
  })
```

The error I'm receiving is :

```
  [TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'request']
```

Here is the twit module git : https://github.com/ttezel/twit/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I understand. [Here's the code of `T.get`](https://github.com/ttezel/twit/blob/master/lib/twitter.js#L43):

```
Twitter.prototype.get = function (path, params, callback) {
  return this.request('GET', path, params, callback)
}
```

As you can see, it expects `this`  to have the method `request`. However, because we used `wrapAsync` without caring about the execution context ([accessed with `this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)), it fails.

Consider this example (you can copy/paste that in your browser console):

```
var obj = {
  foo : 'foo',
  logThis : function() {
    console.log(this);
  }
};
```

If we execute `obj.logThis()` we have: `Object { foo: "foo", logThis: obj.logThis() }`
[But if we do the following...](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#As_an_object_method)

```
var otherLogThis = obj.logThis;
otherLogThis();
```

It logs the `Window` object because we got the function out of its context!

How to solve that issue? Binding the function? Tricky call?
Nope, Meteor has the solution. [`wrapAsync` can have *two* parameters](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_wrapasync)... The second one is the context!

```
var Tget = Meteor.wrapAsync(T.get, T);
```

---

If you want to learn more about JavaScript contexts, I suggest this book :
https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/
<sub>It is free and open-source and I am not affiliated in any way other than my deepest affection and tender memories of feeling my brain growing in all kinds of funny ways when I read it.</sub>

Comment: Okay, this makes sense! Thanks a bunch @Kyll! I just need to understand everything you said so I'll need to do some extra research.