# Accessing variables from HTTP.get

Tags: javascript, meteor, scope

I'm trying to access a variable named city in the Meteor Accounts.onCreateUser user creation function and have not been successful in my attempts to do so. I have tried to return city at the end of the HTTP.get call and have also tried creating the city var outside of HTTP.get and simply setting city without using var but none of these things seems to have worked. When console.log(city) runs it does accurately output the desired information so this variable must not be the issue. If I am making a nube mistake forgive me.

```
Accounts.onCreateUser( function (options, user) {

if (options.profile) {

  options.profile.picturelrg = "http://graph.facebook.com/" + user.services.facebook.id + "/picture/?type=large";
  user.profile = options.profile;
  options.profile.picturesm = "http://graph.facebook.com/" + user.services.facebook.id + "/picture/?type=small";
  options.profile.messenger = "https://www.messenger.com/t/" + user.services.facebook.id;


 HTTP.get("http://ipinfo.io", function (error, result) {
    var place = JSON.parse(result.content);
    var city = place.city;
    console.log(city);

  });


  options.profile.city = city;


}

  return user;

});
```

Comment: `HTTP.get()` is asynchronous, so it executes separately while the script continues. `city` isn't accessible yet when you try to use it. You have to refactor and set the value separately. Try [Thinking Asynchronously (NodeCasts)](http://nodecasts.net/episodes/5-thinking-asynchronously).

Comment: Thanks for the comment and answer. "place" and "city" are now successfully saving to the db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *technically* correct repose to this is that you need to use the synchronous version of `HTTP.get`. See the [docs](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/http_call) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31664423/why-is-undefined-being-returned-for-meteor-call-in-client) for examples.

However there's a more fundamental issue: you're trying to grab the user's location data but `onCreateUser` only runs on the server. So even if you do solve this problem, you'll end up with the same data in each user's profile. You'll need to run the `get` on the client and update via a method. Try something like this:

```
Accounts.createUser(options, function(err) {
  if (!err) {
    HTTP.get(..., function(err, result) {
      var city = ...;
      var place = ...;
      Meteor.call('updateProfileWithCityandPlace', city, place);
    });
  }
});

Meteor.methods({
  updateProfileWithCityandPlace: function(city, place) {
    check(city, String);
    check(place, String);

    Meteor.users.update(this.userId, {
      $set: {'profile.city': city, 'profile.place': place}
    });
  }
});
```